# How to use components in different ways (React)

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, classname

I want to use simple components in different way and different ui rendering
For example a dropdown rendering a list may have several ui according to the page or context (=> padding, margins, font size and other css properties might change)
should I:

- implement it by overwriting in the parent component (target css properties of the child component and apply them my css needs - at cost that if change happens in the child component like change in classname or what  might break the parent design)
- Pass flags to the component to handle those design and at cost that each component handle the design of each parent

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches to this and everybody has his own preferences.
I usually solve this by supporting the `className` property. The class is accepted as a prop and applied to the root. So it is easy to change things like outer `margins` or the `background-color`. I usually discourage modifications of deeply nested elements.

Example:

```
import classnames from 'clsx';
import style from './button.module.scss';

export const Button = ({ content, onClick, className }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={classnames(style.buttonRoot, className)}
      onClick={onClick}>
        {content}
    </div>
  );
};
```

and if I want to modify it anywhere I can do it thus:

```
import { Button } from './Button';
import style from './productView.module.scss';

// ...

<Button content={'Show products'} className={style.showProdButton} onClick={showProd} />
```

and

```scss
.show-prod-button {
  background-color: #562873;
  margin-left: 32px;
}
```